# How to open windows' service-specific event log

Tags: winapi, event-log

We need to read service-specific event log "Microsoft-Windows-TerminalServices-LocalSessionManager/Operational" programmatically. Following code

```
LPWSTR pwsLogName = L"Microsoft-Windows-TerminalServices-LocalSessionManager/Operational";
HANDLE hEventLog = OpenEventLog(nullptr, pwsLogName);
```

results opening "Application" log instead of required.

In the same time command line utility wevtutil can succesfuly read needed log:

```
wevtutil query-events Microsoft-Windows-TerminalServices-LocalSessionManager/Operational
```

What are we doing wrong?

Comment: `OpenEventLog` is part of the legacy [Event Logging API](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa363652). Vista introduced the [Windows Event Log API](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa385780), which is where you will find this Terminal Services event channel. You can query and render events from this channel via [`EvtQuery`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa385466), [`EvtNext`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa385405), and  [`EvtRender`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa385471) (e.g. as XML). Close all handles with `EvtClose`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Finally we've found OpenEventLog() is dead and we need to use Evt* functions ([EvtQuery](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa385466) & company)

Answer (score 1):

The behaviour is by design; see: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/winbase/nf-winbase-openeventloga

Todo: check if registry key exists first, then use `openEventLog()` if succeeded.

```
   _stprintf_s(szKeyName, _T("System\\CurrentControlSet\\Services\\EventLog\\%s"),szLogName);
    dwRet = RegOpenKey(HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE, szKeyName, &hKey);
    if (ERROR_SUCCESS == dwRet)
    { 
        RegCloseKey(hKey);
        // continue with openEventLog()
```